# What does this line of code mean in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

What does this do?

```
<script>window.jQuery || document.write("<script src='js/libs/jquery-1.6.2.min.js'>\x3C/script>")</script>
```

Comment: It looks like it's attempting to see if jQuery is installed and including jquery if it's not.

Comment: Add a `script` tag for the jQuery library if it doesn't exist (the first part).

Comment: For completeness, the reason it doesn't explicitly use `</script>` is because the HTML parser will interpret that *immediately* and screw everything up.

Comment: ALL of Y'all are _skirting around_ the fact that @silentbang wants to know is **"Why the F?" IS this -> THIS WAY!?!.**  SO much `js` is - _SIMPLY inscrutable_. i'm sure this question springs from [this library](https://github.com/lokesh/color-thief).. it DOESNT work if you "just include jQuery like a normal person"..  yet they make no mention of how, or why this method was done/works....  This kind of un-researchable, completely esoteric syntactical madness makes javascript (and interpreting other people's code)... SO agonizing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This includes jQuery if it is not already defined.

```
if (typeof window.jQuery === 'undefined') {
    document.write("<script src='js/libs/jquery-1.6.2.min.js'>\x3C/script>");
}
```

Is basically the same thing

Comment: you mean `if (typeof window.jQuery === 'undefined')`, `window.jQuery === null` is `false` if `undefined`

Comment: yeah, I goofed, because I didn't just want to write `if (window.jQuery)` to further explain what was going on. Thanks I'll update

Answer (score 1):

If jQuery is not already loaded to your page and Load it from the location mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

IF jQuery isn't called in recently page, it's calling jQuery with adding this line to page :

```
<script src='js/libs/jquery-1.6.2.min.js'>\x3C/script>
```